# ip dhcp class command

Tags: ip, cisco-ios, dhcp

Here is a DHCP configuration that we have here:

```
ip dhcp class range
ip dhcp pool abc
 network 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router ...
 class range
  address range 10.10.10.10 10.10.10.254
```

My question is, would that be possible to create another pool and re-use the class "range" with another pool of address ? Or would that cause problems ?

Basically, I want to do this :

```
ip dhcp pool xyz
 network 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router ...
 class range
   address range 192.168.0.10 192.168.0.254
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to configure it on GNS, and it worked just fine.

I could re-use the same dhcp class in two different pools, with two different ranges.